# Ajax content get's loaded inside the wrong div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a bug that I can't find the cause of. Maybe someone has had this before and could point me to the cause? I have 2 div's, 1 is playerlist and the other is chat. Content of both is being loaded using ajax. Everything works fine for hours/sometimes even days. But at some point the playerlist get's loaded inside the chat div.

load chat:

```js
function getchatResult1(){   
    var cProId1 = $('#chat1').attr('proc-id');
    jQuery.post("include/chat.php?ProcessId="+cProId1,function( data ) {
        jQuery("#chat1").html(data);
        jQuery("#chat1").animate({ scrollTop: $("#chat1").prop("scrollHeight")}, 0);
    });
}
```

load player list:

```js
function getplayResult1(){   
    var pProId1 = $('#uList1').attr('proc-id');
    jQuery.post("include/playerlist.php?ProcessId="+pProId1,function( data ) {
        jQuery("#uList1").html(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make the HTML empty before rendering the content into that div.

**For Chat:**

```
function getchatResult1(){
        var cProId1 = $('#chat1').attr('proc-id');
        jQuery.post("include/chat.php?ProcessId="+cProId1,function( data ) {
            jQuery("#chat1").html('');
            jQuery("#chat1").html(data);
            jQuery("#chat1").animate({ scrollTop: $("#chat1").prop("scrollHeight")}, 0);
        });
    }
```

**For Playlist:**

```
function getplayResult1(){
        var pProId1 = $('#uList1').attr('proc-id');
        jQuery.post("include/playerlist.php?ProcessId="+pProId1,function( data ) {
            jQuery("#uList1").html('');
            jQuery("#uList1").html(data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I will try that out, but still I can't figure out how the player list goes inside the chat div.
Edit: I tried it out and this makes it worse, now the chat is flickering. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: As mentioned, currently both have different functions to fetch data and render using ajax. For that need to check your application code as it might be displayed from somewhere else.

Comment: I don't understand what u mean right now? The functions are the once that display the content.

Comment: Yes, functions are written once. However, do you appending any other content elsewhere outside these functions?

Comment: Nope not regarding the chat or player list.

Comment: We can connect to check with issue whenever you're available. Need to debug it runtime.